# How to call a command inside a script?

Tags: hackmud

Most of the commands you can do in the game are typed like this in the console: `chats.tell{to:"John Doe", msg:"Hello World!"}`

How can I do something similar in one of my script?

Give me examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands called inside a script are written a little bit differently. You first have to prefix the command with `#s.` and the followed by the rest of the command `chats.tell`. To pass your keys you have to do it as a function parameter like so:

```
#s.chats.tell({to:"John Doe", msg:"Foo Bar"});
--> Foo Bar
```

The major difference with passing your keys is that you need to surround the `{ }` with `( )`.

You can also replace those string values with variables:

```
var message = "Hello World!";
#s.chats.tell({to:"John Doe", msg:message + " I am not Adele"});
--> Hello World! I am not Adele
```

As you can see, you can also add something after your variable. it can be a number, a string or even another variable.

If you want to execute a script made by another player, its the same thing. lets say the script from `John` is called `dance`. In your command window you would type `John.dance{some:"value"}`. In your script you would write this:

```
#s.John.dance({some:"value"});
```

It works the same way with every commands.